# Return js code from an action without using js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of doing:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    respond_to { |format| format.js }
  end

  #edit.js.erb
  // some js code
```

is there any way to do the same thing in a controller's action like this:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    respond_to { |format| format.js /* some js code*/ }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some codes like this

```
format.js { render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');" }
```

Also

```
format.js { render :js => "window.location.replace('#{your_url(@object)}');" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to :js

def edit
   respond_with { @user = User.find params[:id] }
end
```